# How to re-scale an array according to its unique elements?

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique

I want to re-scale an array within `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the number of unique elements of the array. For example, if the array has 4 unique elements like this:

```
array = [0; 0; 0; 3; 3; 3; 3; 5; 5; 5; 6; 6]
```

then the output would be re-scaled within `0` to `3`. So for the above array, it would be:

```
output =[0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 3; 3]
```

How to do this?

Comment: Do you just want to divide every element by 2?

Comment: Arranged from `0`  to ***`2`***? How exactly? Last 3 elements of your desired array are ***`3`*** (not from 0 to 2)

Comment: dear@gnovice for example if my array is [0;0;0; 3;3; 7;7;7;7]. the desired output will be 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2  just re-arrange the array sequentially

Comment: sorry @SardarUsama I have corrected the question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace each unique value by a number from 0 to the total number of unique values minus 1, labeling them in the order that they first appear in the array, then you can use the third output from the function [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) like so:

```
array = [0; 0; 0; 3; 3; 3; 3; 5; 5; 5; 6; 6];
[~, ~, label] = unique(array, 'stable');
label = label-1;

label =

     0
     0
     0
     1
     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     2
     3
     3
```

Comment: dear @gnovice i have got this error !                                                       Error using cell/unique (line 85)
Input A must be a cell array of strings.

Error in (line 68)
[~, ~, index] = unique(array, 'stable');